# Hazelcast MapStore configure read chunk size

Tags: java, performance, store, hazelcast

I am using my own MapStore implementation in our Hazelcast Nodes. The Store is accessing an MSSQL Database for loading.
Even though I have assigned unreasonably high amount of memory to the JVM, after loading the whole keySet it doesn't seem to process more than an average of 6 keys at a time. This way the initial loading process is unacceptably slow.

One workaround I am using right now is that I have setup the MapStore to be eager and not lazy in loading, this way, the data *should be* already available by the time it will be needed. I'd prefer the store to be lazy and only access the data when it is needed, but with this performance it takes *minutes* for it to be ready.

Does anyobody know how the read chunk size can be configured for Hazelcast MapStore? I would say the 2K keys should be no struggle for the system.

```
[cached13] DEBUG MyMapStoreImpl l:72 - LoadAllKeys loaded: 2427 keys
[cached4] DEBUG MyMapStoreImpl l:62 - loadAll() since begun: 1504 ms Curr.Keys: 6
[cached17] DEBUG MyMapStoreImpl l:62 - loadAll() Since begun: 1862 ms Curr.Keys: 5
[cached6] DEBUG MyMapStoreImpl l:62 - loadAll() since begun: 2436 ms Curr.Keys: 8
```

Answer (score 1):

`loadAll` is called for each partition. Since Hazelcast have 271 partitions by default, this makes around 9 keys per partition. So I think there is no problem in this part. Having around this much keys in each iteration is expected behaviour. You can observe that key size for each call will be bigger if you've more data.
What I kindly suggest to you is to check your MSSQL query performance, imho your query's performance might be the bottleneck.